# How to make one of the row in SwipeListview open while starting activity

Tags: android, android-listview, swipeview

I am working on a project where i have to implement swipelistview. I found one of this in https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview. The thing i want to do to make any of the list item in swipelistview to be opened by default while starting an activivity

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a default behavier that does it, but you can do it manually. In your list adapters' "getView" function, add this line:

```
((SwipeListView)parent).openAnimate(position);
```

Please be advised that list adapters recycle views. If you need views to maintain their open/closed state when they dissapear off the screen and come back, you should have a way to determine if a view should be open or closed in your "getView" function. Otherwise adapter will reuse the state view was in when it rolled off the screen. You can close the view by calling

```
((SwipeListView)parent).closeAnimate(position);
```